# C++ specify non-templated version of function when calling

Tags: c++, templates

I wonder, is there a way to force calling non-template function, like:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T&);

void foo(const int&);

void bar()
{
   int a;
   foo(a); // templated version is called, not a usual function
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may do

```
foo(const_cast<const int&>(a));
```

or

```
foo(static_cast<const int&>(a));
```

or via intermediate variable

```
const int& crefa = a;
foo(crefa);
```

or with wrapper:

```
foo(std::cref(a));
```

or alternatively specify `foo`:

```
static_cast<void(&)(const int&)>(foo)(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to make a cast const like this :

```
foo(const_cast<const int &>(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is you have use `const` in the usual function. And in the template it is not `const T&` as parameter. That is why template version is called. Also you can use change the parameter to `(const int&)a` instead of simply passing `a`

Comment: Yes, but the question is how to specify that I need to call usual function with some conversion.

Comment: How about calling foo(5) in void bar()?

Answer (score 0):

```
foo((const int&)a);
```

Calls int version.